# Неправильное число из класса span

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Код:

```
doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.layta.ru/rvi-ipc31ms-ir.html").get();
Element priceElement = doc.select("span.price").get(0);
float price = Float.parseFloat(priceElement.text().substring(0, priceElement.text().lastIndexOf(" ")).replaceAll(" ", ""));
System.out.println("!X "+price);
```

Почему то возвращает цифру 11042. Должно быть 6600.

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Что именно тут нужно угадать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что Вы парсите не тот документ.

Замените `doc` на `doc2` во второй строке, тогда будет выводится желаемые `6600.0`.

Comment: Мда, стыдно мне!))